# Are boost iterators better than regular c++ iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

Why it is better to use boost iterators over the regular c++ iterators ? 
I don't understand The answer given in the boost library documentation:

> The iterator categories defined in C++98 are extremely limiting because they bind together two orthogonal concepts: traversal and element access. For example, because a random access iterator is required to return a reference (and not a proxy) when dereferenced, it is impossible to capture the capabilities of `vector<bool>::iterator` using the C++98 categories

Does this mean that boost iterators are better even if the containers we use are the std containers ?

Comment: One reason std iterators are better is that they don't need boost.

Comment: Also, we have moved on a bit from C98.

Comment: boost iterators in this context are for the person writing some new iterator, ie. for their own new container, or a new iterator do an existing container. You can't just use say you want to use a boost::iterator instead of a std::iterator with std::containers because for instance std::vector::begin() already defines what iterator type it is going to return

Comment: @NeilButterworth: In what way have we moved on, with respect to iterator categories? As far as I'm aware, iterators are still required to return a reference when dereferenced.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator iterators aren't required to return any particular kind of value when dereferenced.